# API for network

Tags: c#, networking

I have to write a program with c# to find the printers which have same logos over netbios protocol 
The printers are in different subnets and they are netbios enabled
They have been connected with each other by workgroup network
Is there any special API for this aim?

Comment: I've removed your [tag:apl] tag as you clearly meant the [tag:api] tag, but that shouldn't be used either. See the latter's info.

Comment: Oh yes sorry that was my mistake 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a project that needs WMI.